# ZF2 multi-select form preselect values ManyToMany

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2, many-to-many, multi-select

I can't get to preselect values in a multiselect form element representing a many to many relation.

In my model `$admin` I have the proper data : an ArrayCollection containing the correct CampsTypes but in the form I can't get the multiselect to preselect the proper options.

Admins model

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection CampsTypes $campstypes
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CampsTypes", inversedBy="admins", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="campstypes_admins",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="admins_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="campstypes_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $campstypes;
```

CampsType model

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection Admins $admins
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Admins", mappedBy="campstypes", cascade={"persist"})
 */
private $admins;
```

Then I define my form select element as follow

```
        [
            'type' => 'DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectSelect',
            'name' => 'campTypes',
            'required' => false,
            'options' => [
                'object_manager' => $this->getServiceLocator()->get(EntityManager::class),
                'target_class'   => CampsTypes::class,
                'property'       => 'title',
                'label'          => 'Type de camps autorisés',
                'instructions'   => 'Ne rien sélectionner si edition d\'un super admin',

            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'class'    => '',
                'multiple' => 'multiple',
            ]
        ],
```

And finally here is my action to receive the form

```
protected function saveAdmin(Admins &$admin, &$form, &$msg)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    /** @var CampTypesService $serviceCampTypes */
    $serviceCampTypes = $this->getServiceLocator()->get(CampTypesService::class);

    $form->bind($admin);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if (empty($data['password'])) {
            $form->remove('password');
        }
        $form->setData($data);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            if (isset($data['campTypes'])) {
                $ids = $form->get('campTypes')->getValue();
                $campsTypes = new ArrayCollection($serviceCampTypes->getCampTypesByIds(array_values($ids)));
                foreach ($campsTypes as &$campsType) {
                    /** @var CampsTypes $campsType*/
                    $campsType->addAdmin($admin);
                }
                $admin->setCampTypes($campsTypes);
            }
            $em->persist($admin);
            $em->flush();
            $msg = 'Sauvegarde des données effectuée';
            return;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

I'm getting out of solution to try.
Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made it work !

basically my main problem is that I was not using proper Doctrine naming convention for the fields name of the form.

So I had to reverse engineer my DB into doctrine entities to compare with what I had done to understand where it was not working.
And also to set the model in both end (admins in camptype and camptypse in admin) for the whole shabang to work.

Here are the working classes :

Admin form:

```
[
    'type' => ObjectSelect::class,
    'name' => 'campstypes',
    'required' => false,
    'options' => [
        'object_manager' => $this->getServiceLocator()->get(EntityManager::class),
        'target_class'   => CampsTypes::class,
        'property'       => 'title',
        'label'          => 'Type de camps autorisés',
        'instructions'   => 'Ne rien sélectionner si edition d\'un super admin',

    ],
    'attributes' => [
        'class'    => '',
        'multiple' => 'multiple',
    ]
],
```

Admin Controller:

```
protected function saveAdmin(Admins &$admin, &$form, &$msg)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    /** @var CampTypesService $serviceCampTypes */
    $serviceCampTypes = $this->getServiceLocator()->get(CampTypesService::class);

    $form->bind($admin);

    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
        if (empty($data['password'])) {
            $form->remove('password');
        }
        $form->setData($data);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            if (isset($data['campstypes'])) {
                $ids = $form->get('campstypes')->getValue();
                $campsTypes = new ArrayCollection($serviceCampTypes->getCampTypesByIds(array_values($ids)));
                foreach ($campsTypes as &$campsType) {
                    /** @var CampsTypes $campsType*/
                    $campsType->addAdmin($admin);
                }
                $admin->setCampstypes($campsTypes);
            }
            $em->persist($admin);
            $em->flush();
            $msg = 'Sauvegarde des données effectuée';
            return;
        }
    }

    return;
}
```

So by renaming properly the fields of my form and models and setting the data in both end model of the relation I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you [read this](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md) ? I have the feeling you're looking for the `ObjectMultiCheckbox` instead of the `ObjectSelect` Form Element.

Examples from my own code

**Usage for a single select** (use case: set/change a default currency for some other entity)

```
$this->add([
    'type' => ObjectSelect::class,
    'required' => true,
    'name' => 'defaultCurrency',
    'options' => [
        'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
        'target_class'   => Currency::class,
        'property'       => 'id',
// Use these commented lines if you wish to use a Repository function ('name' => 'repositoryFunctionName')
//        'is_method'      => true,
//        'find_method'    => [
//            'name' => 'getEnabledCurrencies',
//        ],
        'display_empty_item' => true,
        'empty_item_label'   => '---',
        'label' => _('Default currency'),
        'label_attributes' => [
            'class' => '',
            'title' => _('Default currency'),
        ],
        'label_generator' => function ($targetEntity) {
            /** @var Currency $targetEntity */
            return $targetEntity->getName(); // Generates option text based on name property of Entity (Currency in this case)
        },
    ],
]);
```

**Usage for multiple select** (Use case: add/remove (multiple) roles to/from user)

```
$this->add([
    'name' => 'roles',
    'required' => false,
    'type' => ObjectMultiCheckbox::class,
    'options' => [
        'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
        'target_class'   => Role::class,
        'property'       => 'id',
        'display_empty_item' => true,
        'empty_item_label'   => '---',
        'label' => _('Roles'),
        'label_generator' => function ($targetEntity) {
            /** @var Role $targetEntity */
            return $targetEntity->getName();
        },
    ],
]);
```

---

As a side note: you should really use factories more. I see you using the `ServiceLocator` throughout your class code, you can avoid that by injecting your needs via a Factory.

---

If you need more information, I suggest you have a look at a bunch of my past questions as well. I had quite a few, starting out similar to what you're looking for. Managed to figure quite a few of them out on my own and have tried to describe the solutions in depth.

Comment: Thanks, I had not red this but I actually want to use the `ObjectSelect `.
I actually did found the solution so i'm gonna post the solution in an answer.

Comment: As for the factories I know I should make factories but coming from Magento 2 and a bit of Symfony with self resolving dependencies I found making factories for all classes very inefficient.
Also this project started when ZF2 came out so at the time the recomandation was to use the service locator but you are right I should clean it at some point.